# What does this setVSyncEnabled() do?

Tags: java, lwjgl

I was looking over some of my older code in Java and LWJGL and I can across

`Display.setVSyncEnabled(true);`

I can't remember what is does. I am making another game, and I was wondering if I would need it or not. So all I am looking for is what it does. Yes I am still a learning and am somewhat new to LJWGL, just to clear that up.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch You should post that as an answer

Answer (score 3):

That call to [setVSyncEnabled](http://lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/Display.html#setVSyncEnabled%28boolean%29) enables "vertical synchronization"; a method used to prevent "tearing" by trying to ensure only one frame is calculated and displayed in a given drawing period. Specifically, it enables buffering to ensure that the currently displayed image is fully drawn before displaying the next image.

See also [screen tearing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_tearing).
[image: Simulated screen tearing]